# Execute tests one by one even across browsers

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I am writing my E2E tests with testcafe against a test backend that doesn't support concurrency, i.e. if two tests execute in parallel, the test backend blows up.

When I am testing against one browser only, the tests execute serially. However, when I specify multiple browsers, the tests run serially *per browser*, but the tests get started in each browser at the same time.

I want testcafe to first execute all the tests in one browser, then open the next browser and execute all tests in it, etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestCafe doesn't have a built-in options for that. But you can configure it manually. For example you can setup running in the `package.json` with the [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) module:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test:chrome": "testcafe chrome c:/temp/test.js",
    "test:ie": "testcafe ie c:/temp/test.js",
    "test": "run-s test:chrome test:ie -c"
  }
```

Also you can setup it in the node.js script with [TestCafe Programming API](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/).